# What Kind of Bug is This?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I took a picture of this bug when I was camping with my boyfriend in Ontario, Canada. The little guy (or gal) kept wanting to climb onto my hand which kind of freaked me out. I'd love to know what kind of bug this is!

[image]

Comment: It looks like an assassin bug. [Spined assassin bug](http://somethingscrawlinginmyhair.com/2013/02/13/spined-assassin-bugs/) perhaps?

Comment: Ogre71, I looked at the picture to which you refer,and I think you are correct. It has a smaller abdomen,but it might mean that it is male.